JwtAuthFilter is applied for all requests even for permitted endpoints
I am having some problems with the new Spring Security configuration. I am using the spring boot version 3.1.4 and the spring security version 6.1.4.
In the config file I define that some pages should be accessible without authentication. After that I add my JwtAuthFilter to the chain. However it is called allways. Even for the endpoints that should be allowed. The error page, which is called for 403 errors is for example allowed to be accessed without authentication. Unfortunately it is also tried to authenticated by the jwtAuthfilter, which leads to another 403 error, which leads to a authentication loop. How can i fix that?
This is my config and my filter.
    @Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class WebSecurityConfig {

 private final JwtAuthFilter jwtAuthFilter;
    private final UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

@Bean
    public SecurityFilterChain securityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        return http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {
                    auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/register").permitAll();
                    auth.requestMatchers("/error/**").permitAll();
                })
                .sessionManagement(s -> s.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
                .authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider())
                .addFilterAfter(jwtAuthFilter, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.class)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public UserDetailsService userDetailsService() {
        return username -> {
            RegisteredUser registeredUser = userProfileRepository.findByMail(Email.of(username));
            if (registeredUser == null) {
                throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
            }
            return registeredUser;
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
        DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
        authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(userDetailsService());
        authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
        return authenticationProvider;
    }

    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManager(UserDetailsService userDetailsService,
                                                       PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder) {
        return authentication -> {
            UserDetails user = userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(authentication.getName());
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(authentication.getCredentials().toString(), user.getPassword())) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                        user.getUsername(),
                        user.getPassword(),
                        user.getAuthorities());
            }
            throw new BadCredentialsException("Bad Password");
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(12);
    } //TODO read from properties

}


This is my Filter
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtAuthFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    private final JwtService jwtService;
    private final UserProfileRepository userProfileRepository;

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(@NonNull HttpServletRequest request,
                                    @NonNull HttpServletResponse response,
                                    @NonNull FilterChain filterChain) throws ServletException, IOException {

        final Cookie[] cookies = request.getCookies();

        if (cookies == null || cookies.length == 0) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        Optional<Cookie> authorizationCookie = Arrays.stream(cookies)
                .filter(cookie -> cookie.getName().equals("Authorization"))
                .findFirst();

        if (authorizationCookie.isEmpty()) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        String token = authorizationCookie.get().getValue();
        String mail = jwtService.extractMail(token);
        if (mail == null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        if (context.getAuthentication() != null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        RegisteredUser user = userProfileRepository.findByMail(Email.of(mail));
        if (user == null) {
            filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
            return;
        }

        if (jwtService.isTokenValid(token, user)) {
            var authenticationToken = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                    user,
                    null,
                    user.getAuthorities());
            authenticationToken.setDetails(new WebAuthenticationDetailsSource().buildDetails(request));
            context.setAuthentication(authenticationToken);
        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }
}


there is a reason this type of filter does not exist in Spring security and that reason is that JWTs should not be used as sessions. So my question is why are you building custom home made security and not using the built in JWT featured that comes with spring security. Why use a security framework if you have no interest in using its features?

i guess because i don't know better and ask people to help me do better. instead of talking like that you could help me and show me how it should be done. i would really appreciate it.

sure, read the docs, there is chapter called JWT before asking here.

You can override a method named shouldNotFilter and set your conditions to avoid the filter.
  @Override
  protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) throws ServletException {
     return condition;
 }

you can follow the documentation shouldNotFilter Doc

Does this also not duplicate code (all endpoints marked with permitall) from the config?

habibi @Kareem, you have to differentiate between the FilterChain concept and the authorities concept, the FilterChain is a series of step should be applied on the request before it reaches the controller layer, where the permitAll is a step to ignore the security context check in the current request.

jazakullahu khayran habibi

Your filter will be called for each request, unless and until you create a separate SecurityFilterChain with a different base route. You can add check to bypass specific routes in your filter:
if (request.getRequestURI().contains("/login") || request.getRequestURI().contains("/register")) {
 
    filterChain.doFilter(request, response);

}


Does this not duplicate code (all endpoints marked with permitall) from the config?

why would you allow all routes without authentication ?

I mean those:  http.authorizeHttpRequests(auth -> {                     auth.requestMatchers("/").permitAll();                     auth.requestMatchers("/login").permitAll();                     auth.requestMatchers("/register").permitAll();                     auth.requestMatchers("/error/**").permitAll();                 }) Everytime i would change it here, i would need to duplicate the change or not?
